# rCharts no longer works in a shiny application while using highcharter also

Tags: javascript, highcharts, shiny, rcharts, r-highcharter

I have a shiny application where I use highcharter and rCharts,

I've noticed that the charts made by rCharts bug since I load highcharter also,
there are some buttons that are added with no explanation

[image]

Can you help me resolve this problem please ?

Comment: try this `hc_annotationsOptions(yourdata, enabledButtons = F)`

Comment: Thanks very much !!

Comment: I added it as answer for future reference

Answer (score 0):

Try `hc_annotationsOptions(yourdata, enabledButtons = F)`